# Is there a full working example for an editable jsGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am looking for a real working  exemple with static local data and one or several editable columns for  the jQuery Plug in jsGrig.

Unfortunately exemples on official website (http://js-grid.com/demos/) are not full and  work with hidden datas and does not work when I copy them.

Is there a complete working example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link
http://js-grid.com/demos/basic.html

Save it with browser
Json data that populates the grid is in db.js

Comment: I'm looking forward to use the js-grid, its similar to datatables but simpler from what I see